# Changing the src of an image with JavaScript does not cause the image to change

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle an image if I click on it. The JavaScript does seem to replace the image, however, the updated image does not appear on the screen. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
<div><img id="light" src="images/light_off.png" width="200px"></div>
</html>
```

and my JavaScript code:

```
var light_src = document.getElementById('light').src;

var image = light_src.substring(light_src.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

light.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (image == "light_off.png"){
        alert("1");
        light_src = "file:///H:/mydir/images/light_on.png";
    }
    else {
        alert("2");
        light_src = "file:///H:/mydir/images/light_off.png";
    }
});
```

The source does seem to be changing because each time I click on the image, the alert toggles between 1 and 2. However, the image does not appear to change on the screen.

I have verified that both images work by copying the URL into the browser address bar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason this got a downvote? If you are going to downvote please explain why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the value of `light_src`, not the element's source. In other words, `light_src` is a copy of the source, and changing it does not change the images source.

Instead of storing the source in a variable, you should just store the image element, like this:

```
// The image URLs
const imageOn = 'file:///H:/mydir/images/light_on.png'
const imageOff = 'file:///H:/mydir/images/light_on.png'

// Store the image element to use later
const imageElement = document.getElementById('light') 

// Add the event listener
imageElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (imageElement.src === imageOn) {
    imageElement.src = imageOff
    console.log('Switched light off')
  } else {
    imageElement.src = imageOn
    console.log('Switched light on')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `.src` with the selector

```js
var light=document.getElementById('light');
var image = light.src.substring(light.src.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

light.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (image == "light_off.png"){
        console.log(light.src);
        light.src = "file:///H:/mydir/images/light_on.png";
    }
    else {
        console.log(light.src);
        light.src = "file:///H:/mydir/images/light_off.png";
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
<div><img id="light" src="images/light_off.png" width="200px" alt="image"></div>
</html>
```